# Can I validate just a Page/Validation Group with OnClientClick?

Tags: c#, validation, webforms, linkbutton

This is my code:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
OnClientClick="Page_ClientValidate(); if(Page_IsValid==false) { console.log('validate'); return false; }" 
ID="LinkButton1" 
ValidationGroup="validPanel1" 
runat="server">Check</asp:LinkButton>
```

but when I click on it, it try to validate the whole Page. I just need to validate the `validPanel1`'s Page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by simply provide the validation group name to `Page_ClientValidate`

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="Page_ClientValidate('Your_ValidationGroup_Name'); if(Page_IsValid==false) { console.log('validate'); return false; }" 
ID="LinkButton1" ValidationGroup="validPanel1" runat="server">Check</asp:LinkButton>
```

kindly check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119488/asp-net-validation-with-validation-group-calling-page-clientvalidate-not-working). It's about another problem but he first do what you want to do.