# Asp.Net validation check at client side

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am validating data at client side in asp.net validator by using following code snipet.

```
function ValidateData(){
if (!Page_ClientValidate("Validator1") || !Page_ClientValidate("Validator2")) {
     return false;
}
else{
     return true;
}
```

I called it on submit of button. But it showing validation messages of Validator1 group. Its not showing me validation messages of Validator2 group.

Comment: So you want to validate both group of controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just gone through :
see this link question , here its told -  || operator short-circuits if the left condition is true.

[Does a javascript if statement with multiple conditions test all of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930499/does-a-javascript-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions-test-all-of-them)

If you want both , then cant you try like this :

```
function ValidateData(){

if (!Page_ClientValidate("Validator1")) 
{

    if (!Page_ClientValidate("Validator2")) 
    {
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
         return false;
    }


     return false;
}
else
{
     return true;
}

}
```

Just a random try , this code :)

Rigin

Comment: Hi Rigin, Thanks for your answer. I tried it here but still it didnt solve my problem. similarly I tried  function ValidateData(){                   var res = true;                                                 if (!Page_ClientValidate("validator1")) {
                    res = false;
                }
                if (!Page_ClientValidate("validator2")) {
                    res = false;
                } return res; }

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560812/page-clientvalidate-with-multiple-validationgroups-how-to-show-multiple-summ
Below one answer is marked also . Can you try this : 
 function fnJSOnFormSubmit() {
        var isGrpOneValid = Page_ClientValidate("valGrpOne");
        var isGrpTwoValid = Page_ClientValidate("valGrpTwo");

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) { ....

Comment: Thanks Rigin.. This above second solution solved by problem.. Thank you very much..