# ValidationSummary is not displaying error message on server side after group assignment

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, validationsummary, validationgroup

I have a ValidationSummary control that was initially working with all my validation controls at the beginning, however, later on when I assigned my validation controls to groups, ie, give them a group name in the `ValidationGroups` attribute, it does not seem to show the error messages of the validation controls that fails the validation on the server side. I'm using the call to `Page.Validate()` to validate all the controls on the server side. Has anyone ran into this issue before?

I experimented a bit with a simple page and noticed that this happens when you assign a CustomerValidator to a group but the problem goes away without the group.

Here is Start.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Start.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.Start" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CausesValidation ="true" OnClick="Button1_Click" style="height: 26px"/>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="Group1" Display="None" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationGroup="Group2" Display="None" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" Display="None" ValidationGroup="Group2" ErrorMessage="Message for display in validation summary" OnServerValidate="cusCustom_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is Start.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class Start : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void cusCustom_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
        {
            e.IsValid = false;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Validate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: @SainPradeep, Added in code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign ValidationGroups to RequiredFieldValidators and CustomValidators, you also need to assign a ValidationGroup to your ValidationSummary, as you're using Display="None" (which means your validation controls will only show their ErrorMessage in their associated ValidationSummary control).

Since you have Group1 and Group2, you need to add 2 ValidationSummary controls, one for Group1, and the other for Group2. Like this...

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group2" />
```

Another thing to note is that CustomValidators will only validate after RequiredFieldValidators, so you won't see the error message from your CustomValidator until your RequiredFieldValidators pass validation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem that I am now facing when I add a new ValidationSummary control for each of the specified group is that it is displaying the error message for controls that belong in other groups. So I am getting a duplicate error message in each of the new ValidationSummary that I have added on.

Comment: Sounds as though you've not configured your groups correctly. Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595546/validationsummary-not-working-when-validationgroup-is-specified which discusses handling ValidationGroups in more detail.